# How do I query a database with AngularJS's $resource factory for a specific set of rows?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, web, mean-stack

I'm building an app using AngularJS and the MEAN Stack, and was wondering if it was possible to use the $resource factory to query a MongoDB database for a set of rows that have a certain value in one of their columns.

For example, if I wanted to build a Todo app, and I had a table with a column containing a persons username and a column with a string that had a reminder, is it possible to query the database for all the rows that have a particular username in the username column? Or, do I have to do something like this:

Todo.service.ts:

```
export function TodoResource($resource) {
    'ngInject'; 
    return $resource('/api/todo/:query', {
        id: '@_id'
        query: '';
    });
}
```

app.js

```
var list = [];
this.Todo.query().$promise.then( (data) => {

        for(let datum of data){
            if(datum.userName == email){
                list.push(datum);
            }
        }
    });
```

In this sample case, I'm not really querying the database, just getting the entire table and filtering the results by myself. Is this the only way to do it, or can I directly query the database?

Comment: Not from front end directly. A db query has to be made using server side code. Front end only manages what server side returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using NODE and MongoDB, then you must be using Mongoose.

For this purpose its better to filter data on server not on client, as it would
 - Decrease the amount of data on network
 - Prevent unwanted data to be sent to client

Also, If you dont want to manually filter the data on server with a function, there is a function in mongoose

```
var query = collection.find({_id: '001'});
query.exec(function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        res.json(err);
    }
    if (results) {
        res.json(results);
    }
});
```

this will add filter in query to mongodb before executing it, and will fetch only records having

```
id= 001;
```

i.e. filtered data

By this you will not have to filter data manually, MongoDB will handle it all.

You can send the id in the request URL

```
localhost:8080/collectionName/001
```

on NODE server:

```
function (req, res) {
    var mainUrl = req.url.split("/");
    if (mainUrl.length > 2) {
        query = collection.find({_id: mainUrl[2]});
    } else {
        query = collection.find();
    }
    query.exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        if (results) {
            res.json(results);
        }
    });
}
```

You can also make your url like:

```
localhost:8080/collectionName?id='001'
```

then on server:

```
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
var queryFactors = url_parts.query;
var id= JSON.parse(queryFactors["id"]);
```

and use above code again for queering.

Hope this helps.